# Why the setprecision do error ? and what is setprecision

Tags: c++, dev-c++

My teacher gave me this and I got an error when adding

```
«setprecision(3) <<setiosflags(ios::fixed) »
```

Could you tell me why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    float x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,PQ,QR,RS,SP,Keliling;
    cout << "Masukkan koordinat empat titik berbeda (x,y) :\n";
    cout<< "P(x,y):" ;
    cin >> x1>>y1 ;
    cout <<"\n" ;
    cout << "Q(x,y) :" ;
    cin >> x2>>y2 ;
    cout <<"\n" ;
    cout << "R(x,y) :" ;
    cin>> x3>>y3 ;
    cout <<"\n" ;
    cout << "S(x,y) :" ;
    cin >>x4>>y4;
    cout <<"\n" ;

    PQ = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2)+pow(y2-y1,2));
    QR = sqrt(pow(x3-x2,2)+pow(y3-y2,2));
    RS = sqrt(pow(x4-x3,2)+pow(y4-y3,2));
    SP = sqrt(pow(x1-x4,2)+pow(y1-y4,2));

    Keliling = PQ+QR+RS+SP;
    cout << "Kelilingnya adalah " << Keliling <<" satuan";
    «setprecision(3) <<setiosflags(ios::fixed) »
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Your teacher gave you that, surrounding the code with quotation marks. Are you unfamiliar with quotation marks?

Answer (score 4):

Because you misunderstood the instruction. You can't just dump it onto its own line in code at the end of your program and expect it to magically work, and you can't keep the French quotation marks on it.

You need to think logically about what your program does, and in what order. What do you want to accomplish, and how can you tell the computer how to help you accomplish it?

A good start would be Googling `setprecision` to find out what it is and how to use it.

Furthermore, your program has other problems, such as the missing return type for `main`.

Comment: IIRC if the return type is `int`, it can be omitted. Same with `int` parameter types. So `foo(a, b) { return a + b; }` is valid.

Edit: `int` omission from functions seems to be fine, but omission of parameter types wasn't kosher.

Comment: @erip: No, it can't. C++ is not C.

Comment: @erip: That it is accepted by GCC in older, non-strict modes doesn't mean it's a valid C++ program (which it is not). Turn on your compiler warnings. GCC by default has lots of holdover C features enabled when compiling C++ code.

Comment: Understood. Tried to find a standard quote, but was unable with a quick scan. Closest I found was [basic.start.main] 2: _[main] shall
have a return type of type `int`_

Comment: @erip: There's nothing to quote from the standard, really, except for the entirety of the grammar and the rules that say a function has a return type and define where it goes in a function declaration. There's simply no rule to say you can omit it. However, the non-normative compatibility section `[C++14: C.1.6]` describes how this used to be valid in C and no longer is in C++, under the section entitled "Banning implicit int". (I don't have a section number for C++98 but it'll be in there too, showing that this is hardly a recent change!)

Answer (score 3):

`sestprecision` is a manipulator that you can pass into `cout` stream to define how many digits after comma should be displayed so for example:

```
    cout << setprecision(2) << 0.122312 << endl;
```

will result with

```
    0.12
```

it causes error because you have not put it into stream but *nowhere* - it is not a statement!

Comment: then what is then meaning of setiosflags (ios::fixed) ? thanks before

Comment: that allows you to add some  format flags (like for UPPERCASE) - [take a look at this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setiosflags/) - I'm pretty sure that you will find there more interesting info

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the line is that it is not a valid cpp statement

the setprecision statement need to be connected to an output stream and since you are using the standard output. The correction will go like this

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
```

Again just as preferencebean stated, your main function should include a return type.

```
int main() 
{
  //code;
}
```